# "package is configured multiple times", "repository dies not have a release file" and 404 errors when updating

Tags: apt, package-management

I get many errors when I run `sudo apt update` on Ubuntu 16.04`

```
Err:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err:49 http://ppa.launchpad.net/medigeek/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err:10 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
Fetched 5,770 kB in 2min 44s (35.1 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fossfreedom-ubuntu-packagefixes-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fossfreedom-ubuntu-packagefixes-xenial.list:3
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:3
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:4
W: The repository 'htt://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'htt://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'htt://ppa.launchpad.net/medigeek/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/medigeek/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:19 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fossfreedom-ubuntu-packagefixes-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fossfreedom-ubuntu-packagefixes-xenial.list:3
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:3
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:4
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I did an update please see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues here:

1. Multiple configurations, fix:

   1. `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list`

      - Open file `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list`
      - Put a `#` at the beginning of line `2` and `3`
   2. `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fossfreedom-ubuntu-packagefixes-xenial.list`

      - Open file `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fossfreedom-ubuntu-packagefixes-xenial.list`
      - Put `#` at the start of line `2` or `3`
   3. `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list`

      - delete `sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list`
      - Or put a `#` at the start of line `19` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`
   4. Now run update: `sudo apt update`
2. Check you internet connection make sure it's ok.

Comment: one question i d like to ask, when putting  # on lines, how can we get any updates from this lists in source lists?

Comment: I did step 1 and step 2. But the problem with step 3 is xenial-partner.list has only 4 lines.
# channel for the xenial (16.04) partner channel
# 
#:description:This channel contains the partner software for xenial
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

Comment: let me update that @NamanJain

Comment: @solfish putting `#` doesn't stop your updates it just removes duplicate entries in the apt update index

Comment: Still waiting to hear from you @George

Comment: I did an update please see my answer

Comment: Still, I'm unable to use Libreoffice 5.3

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I can't open files larger than 5MB. It stops responding and I've to force close it.

Comment: ok please post a new question about this libreoffice issue